# Use case testing vs Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing

What is the difference between use case testing vs unit testing. In cases where the individual functions cannot be called unless there is a trigger or the scenario is simulated which approach is better?

Answer (score 1):

Use case testing - The Use-Case Testing Technique helps identifying test cases that cover the entire system, on a transaction by transaction basis from the start to finish.

Use case testing helps tester to identify the testing scope at acceptance level.

The bugs are found in use case testing increase the cost of bug fixes.

Unit testing - Unit testing is technique helps developer to find the defect in developed individual module. A unit is the smallest testable part of an application like functions, classes, procedures, interfaces.

Unit testing is a method by which individual units of source code are tested to determine if they are fit for use.

Unit testing helps in simplifying the debugging process.

The bugs are found early in unit testing hence it also helps in reducing the cost of bug fixes.